# Incorrect result of comparison of negative value against rdi register

Tags: c, macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a C, 64 bit program with a function declaration which looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern double wartosc (double a, double b, double x, int n);

int main() {
    printf("%f", wartosc(4, 3, 2, -2));
}
```

The function is implemented in assembler, code:

```
section .text
  global _wartosc

_wartosc:
  cmp rdi, 0
  jl finish
  xorpd xmm0, xmm0
  finish:
  ret
```

Why does the printf function outputs 0? Comparison of the argument against rdi register seems to be invalid

If I understand correctly parameters a, b, x were passed to xmm0, xmm1 and xmm2 registers and the last parameter was in rdi, result is returned by xmm0 register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You declared the parameter as `int`, which is a 32-bit type**.  It's not sign-extended to fill `rdi`, only `edi`.

The top half of RDI is whatever random garbage the caller left there.  In many cases zero, from implicit sign-extension after writing a 32-bit register.

Look at the compiler-generated code for the caller, and look at register values in a debugger.